# How to write variables for media queries in stylus?

Tags: css, media-queries, stylus

At first I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$medium = '@media screen and (min-width: 768px)'
$large = '@media screen and (min-width: 992px)'
$xlarge = '@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)'

.box
    background: #000
    $medium
        background: #111
    $large
        background: #222
    $xlarge
        background: #333
```

Then I used this and it works.

```
medium = 'screen and (min-width: 768px)'
large = 'screen and (min-width: 992px)'
xlarge = 'screen and (min-width: 1200px)'

.box
    background: #000
    @media medium
        background: #111
    @media large
        background: #222
    @media xlarge
        background: #333
```

Why can't I use the technique above?

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope this is a better way of asking.

Answer (score 4):

Because in your first case those variables were parsed as placeholder selectors (see http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/extend.html#extending-placeholder-selectors).

Comment: Thank you, don't know how I missed that in stylus's documents. I guess I'll be sticking to my second option.